# Puppeteer & proxy-chain: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

The below code works perfectly without using proxy-chain, but as soon as I pass the proxy-server argument to puppeteer it will run into a timeout:

```
TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
```

In local development I use any of those for Chromium:

```
PPTR_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
PPTR_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium
```

My first assumption was that proxy-chain doesn't work, but I wrote a separate script which uses proxy-chain and the same credentials to perform a node-fetch and it works flawlessly.

So puppeteer works standalone, and proxy-chain does too, any idea what causes this issue?

Thanks!

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
require('dotenv').config();
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

const proxyChain = require('proxy-chain');
const proxy_host = process.env.PROXY_HOST;
const proxy_username = process.env.PROXY_USERNAME;
const proxy_password = process.env.PROXY_PASSWORD;

exports.getIP = async (req, res, next) => {
    let browser;
    let newProxyUrl;

    try {
        const oldProxyUrl = `http://${proxy_username}:${proxy_password}@${proxy_host}`;
        newProxyUrl = await proxyChain.anonymizeProxy(oldProxyUrl);

        browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: "false",
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
            executablePath: process.env.PPTR_EXECUTABLE_PATH || '/usr/bin/chromium',
            args: [
                `--proxy-server=${newProxyUrl}`,
                `--no-sandbox`,
                `--disable-gpu`,
            ]
        });

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://nordvpn.com/what-is-my-ip/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

        const ip = await page.$eval('.Title.h3.mb-6.js-ipdata-ip-address', el => el.textContent);
        const location = await page.$eval('.js-ipdata-location', el => el.textContent);

        res.status(200).json({ success: true, ip: ip, location: location });
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    } finally {
        if (browser) {
            await browser.close();
            await proxyChain.closeAnonymizedProxy(newProxyUrl, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should definitely console.log(newProxyUrl) so you can check it and share it with us here. It might be some local port that's getting blocked? Or it might not include http:// ?

Comment: @pguardiario I did try this previously, the URL is correct, something like: http://127.0.0.1:60250

Comment: I believe the http:// is required there

Comment: when I copy the url here it doesn't show the http, but it's there

Comment: Maybe try running proxy chain in a separate script / process. Also headless should be either "new" or false (no quotes)